# Fishing Wire From Corner of Attic?

Tags: wiring, attic

I'm running speaker wire from the 2 corners of this room. But one of the corners is way too tight for me to grab the fished wire. And the Fiberglass Wire Pull Rods i'm using are too stiff to bend from with in the room toward me while i'm in the attic.

I've tried to attach a fairly strong magnet to attach to the rod that's coming from the ceiling, but it quickly loses it's hold after a few light tugs.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you were to attach something similar to the end of the wire such as a hex nut that would not easily slip off then you could make up a remote noose on the end of a long stick that looks like this.

[image]
*(proverbial back of envelope sketch)*

Aim the stick down into the tight corner of the attic and lower the noose over the end of the wire with the hex nut. Then securely pull the noose string to capture the wire and pull the stick toward you along with the speaker wire.

Comment: This is a wonderful idea, except, the way im fishing the line, im only leaving enough space that either a fishing rod can get through the hole or the actual speaker line it's self.

Comment: Just used this method to run another cable. Perfection.

Answer (score 3):

For whomever does this again:
I've found it easier to fish monofilament pull line:
[image: pull line]

Tie a large loop it in, tape it to your fishing pole, and retreive it the attic with stick with a hook on it (breaking the tape).

Now tie your wire to the other end of the fishing line and pull.

Answer (score 2):

What I ended up doing was ditching the fishing rod all together and taping a long piece of magnet to the end of the wire I was running with electrical tape.

And on the other side, using a 6 foot long stick and taping about 3 magnets together with electrical tape at the end and I was able to attach the 2 magnets together.

This allowed me to draw the wire toward me and successfully run the cable.